# What is the usage of PVCs in an ADSL modem settings?

Tags: adsl, modem

This is a question from a layman searching for practical information. I can see eight PVCs in the settings of this ADSL modem. Just one of them is connected. As far as I know, they define some sort of virtual circuits between the modem and the ISP. But how can they be helpful? (Please give an example) Can more than one of them be connected simultaneously? Why are there eight of them? Is it decided by the manufacturer of the modem? Unfortunately, information that I found about PVC on the web is quite technical.

Answer (score 1):

*Permanent virtual circuits* are logical links that run besides each other. Multiple PVCs can segregate traffic and are commonly used for VoIP, multimedia streaming or standard Internet traffic.

Which PVCs there are and how they are used is defined by your ISP.